# sorted my nsmutabledictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sorting, nsdictionary

what is the code to sorted this dictionary :

```
{
        "a) Saudi Arabia" =     (
            "2012/06/04 Huge Sandstorm",
            "2011/03/30 Huge Sandstorm"
        );
        "b) Niger" =     (
            "2012/05/27 Huge Sandstorm"
        );
        "c) ****** QUATRE" =     (
            "2011/03/30 7Huge Sandstorm over niger",
            "2011/03/30 8Huge Sandstorm over niger",
        );
    }
```

for my UItableView ?

with this code my titles header section are in order but not the content:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [[states allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    return [allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";       
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];           
    }

    NSArray *allKeys = [states allKeys] ;
    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *curArray = [states objectForKey:curKey];
    curValue = [curArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = curValue; 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;   
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    return cell;  
}
```

Someone can please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//use this code

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
     return [[states allKeys] count];//returns the number of key/object pairs
 }

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
      NSArray *allKeys = [[states allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
      return [allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       NSArray *allKeys = [[states allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
       NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
       NSArray *curArray = [states objectForKey:curKey];

       return [curArray count];
     }

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
          static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

           UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     }
     // Configure the cell...

     //---------- CELL BACKGROUND IMAGE -----------------------------
     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGrey.png"];
     imageView.image = image;
     cell.backgroundView = imageView;
     [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
      [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


     NSArray *allKeys = [[states allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

     NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *curArray = [[states objectForKey:curKey]     sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
     NSString *curValue=@"";
     if([curArray count]>indexPath.row) 
         curValue = [curArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   if(curValue)
       cell.textLabel.text = curValue;

     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

     [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
     return cell;

 }

  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     return 60;

   }
```

may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting your dictionary in `titleForHeaderInSection` but not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Perhaps you could sort your entire dictionary when it's created to save having to re-sort it ever time the `UITableView` is refreshed. This way you would only need to sort it once and then both the keys and values would always be in the correct order for populating your section headers as well as the cells.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful here.If you have doubts let me know. Write this code before calling the tableview.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)]; //pass the key of your dictionary here
[allKeys sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort the `curKey`

```
NSArray *curArray = [states objectForKey:curKey];
//Add this line after currArray
NSArray *sorterCurArray = [curArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
//Use sorterCurArray instead
curValue = [sorterCurArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 write the same code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: too for accessing key

NSArray *allKeys = [[states allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  StoryboardTutorial
//
//  Created by Kurry Tran on 10/20/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize states,datasource,curValue,sortedArray,descriptor;
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setupArray];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)setupArray{

    NSURL *myUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"the link with the dictionary"];
  //  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myUrl usedEncoding:nil error:nil]; //load above string here
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:myUrl];

//    NSString *str =@"# 2012/20110930 Huge Sandstorm over niger# just for the test/20110330 AHuge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 BHuge Sandstorm over niger";

//    NSArray * firstArry = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
//    NSMutableArray *secondArry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Will hold the # titles
//    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //Will hold the strings related to # title
//    for(NSString *firstArryStr in firstArry)
//    {
//        NSArray *tempArry = [firstArryStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
//        NSMutableArray *titleStingsArry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//        for (int i=0; i< [tempArry count];i++) {
//            if (i==0) {
//                NSString *title = [tempArry  objectAtIndex:i];
//                [secondArry addObject:title];
//                [dict setValue:titleStingsArry  forKey:title];
//            } else {
//                [titleStingsArry  addObject:[tempArry  objectAtIndex:i]];
//            }
//        } 
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);

//    }    

//    NSString *myString = @"20110330 AHuge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 BHuge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 CHuge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 1Huge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 2Huge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 3Huge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 4Huge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 5CHuge Sandstorm over niger/20110330 6Huge Sandstorm over niger";
//    NSArray *event = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
//    states = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:event];

    self.states = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: dict];
datasource = [dict allKeys];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"test";



}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [states count];//returns the number of key/object pairs
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [[states allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    return [allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [states allKeys];
    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *curArray = [states objectForKey:curKey];

    return [curArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    // Configure the cell...

    //---------- CELL BACKGROUND IMAGE -----------------------------
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGrey.png"];
    imageView.image = image;
    cell.backgroundView = imageView;
    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    NSArray *allKeys = [[states allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *curArray = [states objectForKey:curKey];

    if([curArray count]>indexPath.row) curValue = [curArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.text = curValue;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSArray *allKeys = [states allKeys];
    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *curArray = [states objectForKey:curKey];
    curValue = [curArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    // detail.state = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.state = curValue;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

}

//- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
//    //normal cell acquisition code
//    
//    NSArray *allKeys = [states allKeys];
//    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
//    NSArray *curArray = [states objectForKey:curKey];
//    NSString *curValue = [curArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    //Do something with the string
//
//}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 60;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```